# Eedit order and shipping methods in Magento 1.5

Tags: magento, admin, edit

When I'm editing order in Magento 1.5 in shipping method section there is a list of all available shipping methods. But when I change number of products or add/delete any product, all shipping methods disappear. Instead of shipping methods there there is a link: Get shipping methods and rates, but when I click it nothing's happend - page reloads and still there are no methods. 
I have no messages in logs, where I can check what is wrong with it?

Comment: Did you find the solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you edit any order from the magento admin, magento will cancel that particular order and will generate a new one with the new order ID. Example if you have order ID **1234567**, by editing this a new order will be generated with the ID **1234567-1**

So once a new order is created from admin or updating products in existing order you will get a link called **Click to change shipping method** . Because shipping methods are dependent on products selected and shipping address provided in shipping address fields.

Now as per the issue you listed that you are not seeing any shipping methods after clicking link. This may arise with the following reasons.

- You may not have shipping methods available as per the products rules (quantity, weights, product price etc).
- you may be putting downloadable product which do not require shipping details
- Another possible reason is that you might have missed shipping address fields.
- you may have any shipping restrictions plugin installed that may applying any restriction rules.
- You may have any java script error in you console. Which is stopping ajax to be completed after clicking the link. (check your browser console window)

You can debug it by your quote object. Try to get your quote object and see what are the information missing there. Is products are their in your corresponding quote objects ? is shipping details are there ?

If you still need any help in debugging let me know I will help you.

Comment: Thank you so much rajat for so detailed response :) i will give it a try and will let you know about the result. But for reasons, neither I have any plugin installed for shipping, nor shipping address fields are missed, and also shipping method should be available as there are no rules set.

Comment: check the first point about product quantity, weight etc... or try enabling flat rate or free shipping methods from system->configuration->shipping Methods and see if you get these shipping methods

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like you have a shipping extension installed? And/or an order editing module? The interaction between shipping modules and orders is precarious at best; developers cannot forsee the varied interactions which occur on our websites.

We just discovered *MageWorx Extended Orders* module. Amazing and reliable. Their overloading of the sales order grid as well as the order view is a great integration, combining order editing, custom shipping rates, allowing customized columns in the sales grid. And the module's price is very fair.

Previously, we used *TinyBrick True Order Edit* in concert with another module for custom shipping rates but they did not play well together... often with the same result you are seeing. Possibly the instability then was that TinyBrick tries a more focused overload of the order view.

Comment: I'm looking for free module or fix - payable modules are out of my budget... :(

Comment: MageWorx one is $149, but I understand not wanting to pay. Here, imho, you receive much more $149 worth of software.